# Docker Install Issue

Tags: apt, docker

I am trying to install Docker using these instructions but I am running to an issue adding the repo

https://linuxhint.com/install_docker_linux_mint/

> xxx@Home-Server:~$ sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable"
>
> [sudo] password for xxx:
>
> Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
>
> Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

I added the key properly and did the steps to install the items for apt to support HTTPS but looks like it cannot connect to the server. Any ideas what I did wrong?

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: "*Could not connect: Connection refused*" is some kind of network problem, and seems unrelated to Ubuntu...or to Mint.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to StackExchange!

It looks like you're trying to install on Mint? Since Mint is based on Ubuntu, you should be able to follow the Docker install guide for Ubuntu here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

That page does have one note regarding Mint:

> Note: The `lsb_release -cs` sub-command below returns the name of your Ubuntu distribution, such as xenial. Sometimes, in a distribution like Linux Mint, you might need to change `$(lsb_release -cs)` to your parent Ubuntu distribution. For example, if you are using `Linux Mint Tessa`, you could use `bionic`. Docker does not offer any guarantees on untested and unsupported Ubuntu distributions.

It looks fairly similar to the commands you are already running:

```bsh
sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io containerd runc
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    gnupg-agent \
    software-properties-common
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
```

It looks like the post you are following has `bionic` hard-coded into the `add-apt-repository` command. That's really the only difference I can spot though. Considering the note I mentioned earlier, that seems correct if you're on Linux Mint Tessa.

---

The specific error you're receiving `Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused` seemed familiar to me so I did a quick search on it and then I remembered! I've seen this error before but it seems odd in this context. I've usually seen this when attempting to run graphical applications in a terminal-only environment (ex: WSL or SSH with no X11 server). Perhaps the command is causing some sort of GUI prompt to appear but you can't see it.

Comment: See _Questions you should avoid_ at https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @K7AAY: While the OP did link to a Mint tutorial, the question is not explicitly about Mint. I believe the intent of that guideline is that Ubuntu users coming here shouldn't have to sift through answers that only work for Mint. This is not the case with my answer. The answer I provided is valid for Ubuntu in general and only has a note regarding Mint.

Comment: "It looks like you're trying to install on Mint?" suggests Mint is accepted here. It is not (op cit.). Mint is different and has its own support site.

Comment: @K7AAY: Is the spirit of that guideline "We don't accept Mint here"? Or is it "We want this to be helpful for Ubuntu users and not specialized to Mint"?

Comment: Discuss it in https://meta.askubuntu.com if you wish, but don't put words in my mouth I didn't speak.

Comment: Not sure what words you are talking about? As stated in the Code of Conduct "tone is hard to decipher online" and perhaps you were reading into my statement something that wasn't there.

Focus has already been derailed from explaining how to do something *on Ubuntu* to the fact that the requester *might* be using Mint. No need for further discussion. I'm satisfied that my response meets the Code of Conduct guidelines. I suggest you review them as well: "Focus on the content," (installing Docker on Ubuntu) "not the person" (*maybe* a Mint user).

Comment: Did I downvote the OP? No. I asked him which OS he used. Did you write the words "We don't accept Mint here"? Yes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108305/discussion-between-kevin-rak-and-k7aay).